# JavaScript function in c# asp.net button click event not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm in a asp.net c# project. I want to print employees card with bar code. So I write a html tag in string variable call `htmlCon` and it will bind a DIV tag in client side (get all employees and loop it for print one by one).
it work fine. but inside the `htmlCon` variable has java script function it will not run in loop.

```
protected void btnGenarate_ClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    ......

    foreach (var item in empDetails)
    {
      htmlCon += ..........+

"<script>"+ 
"$(document).ready(function ()"+
"{ $('#barcode').JsBarcode('"+ item.EmployeeNo + "', { width: 1, height: 30 }); });"+
"</script>" +
"<img id='barcode' class='barcode'/>" +        

"........................................"+
    }
}
```

this code comes with bar code and it will print first round in the loop..I want to run all employees for get bar code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating many images with the same ID, you should generate a new id for each loop iteration.  I would also recommend using a StringBuilder instead of a bunch of string concatenations:

```
    protected void btnGenarate_ClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {             
        StringBuilder htmlCon = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < empDetails.Count; i++)
        {
            htmlCon.AppendFormat("<script>$(document).ready(function () { $('#barcode{0}').JsBarcode('{1}', { width: 1, height: 30 }); });</script><img id='barcode{0}' class='barcode'/>", 
                i.ToString(), empDetails[i].EmployeeNo);

            htmlCon.Append("........................................");
        }

        //To Use StringBuilder value
        string html = htmlCon.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.. I got the answer in this..
$('#barcode{0}').JsBarcode('{1}', { width: 1, height: 30 });